# How can I make 'quickfixtextfunc' work with cfilter using a vim9's "def" function?

Tags: vimscript, gvim, quickfix, vim9script, vim9

On Windows 10, using `gvim`, when editing a file like the following example:

```
foo
foobar
baz
```

As long as I use a `function` and not a `def`, I can do the following and `Cfilter` will work as expected:

```
:function! MyQuickFixTextFunc(lines)
:  return ['']
:endfunction

:set quickfixtextfunc=MyQuickFixTextFunc
:vim /foo/ %
:packadd cfilter
:Cfilter bar
```

However, when using `vim9script`'s `def`, the following `Cfilter` will display `E117: Unknown function: MyQuickFixTextFunc`

```
:def MyQuickFixTextFunc(info: dict<number>): list<string>
:  return ['']
:enddef
:defcompile MyQuickFixTextFunc

:set quickfixtextfunc=MyQuickFixTextFunc
:vim /foo/ %
:packadd cfilter
:Cfilter bar
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong in my attempt to apply `MyQuickFixTextFunc` when using a function defined using `vim9script` syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function created by "def" is script-local by default.  On the other hand, the function created by "function" is global by default.  The 'quickfixtextfunc' option should be set to a global function.  You can prefix the function name with "g:" when defining the function using "def".  Also, you don't need to explicitly call the ":defcompile" command to compile the function.